# how to open instagram app on button click

Tags: ios, instagram

1. Hi all am trying to open instagram app on a button click but am not
   able to  i set Url scheme as instagram in plist also

   ```
   NSString *instagramURL = @"instagram://app"; 
   NSURL *ourURL = [NSURLURLWithString:instagramURL]; 
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:ourURL]) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:ourURL];

   } else {
       //The App is not installed. It must be installed from iTunes code.
       NSString *iTunesLink = @"//Some other Url goes here";
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];

       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"URL error"
             message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"No custom URL defined for %@", ourURL]
             delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
   ```

   i did like this but app not opening  am new to iOS  any help can be
   appreciated

Comment: Please answer this question, I can not open the instagram.  NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",[[assetURL absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],caption]];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open instagram app by username like,

```
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://user?username=USERNAME"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

You can refer [iPhone Hooks of Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) for more ways and details about api!!!

**Update :**

Replace below line,

```
 NSString *instagramURL = @"instagram://app";
```

with

```
   NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
```

You are assigning directly string as url!!

Comment: hello ketan but there is no login in  required in my app normally  app should open if user taps on instagram button in my app and still i dint fixed it how to open with out login and i did not write any thing in  this method

Comment: -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options{

return YES;
}

Comment: yes i did tried  and i  think i did same  thing  but still dint worked for me and noramlly what are the steps to do this task how plist should be and what are the area to be cover to get this job done

Answer (score 3):

Add key Value  In Info.plist File

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>twitter</string>
    </array>
```