# "canOpenURL" is acting weird... or am I?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I find it weird that though canOpenURL(myURL) is false while open(myURL) perfectly redirected to the app I want. What am I doing wrong here?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let instagramUrl = URL(string: "instagram://app")!
    print(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramUrl))    // false
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramUrl) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(instagramUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://instagram.com")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)    // Instagram successfully launched???
        // UIApplication.shared.open(instagramUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)        // This works too
        print("Open failed.")    // Open failed.
    }
}
```

Console:

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://app" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagram"

[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

My Info.plist as below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open instagram app on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803801/how-to-open-instagram-app-on-button-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include your URL *scheme* into `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, not the URL itself.

So, instead of all the items in your current `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, you just need *one* item with the value `instagram` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You literally saved my night!!! I am using the scheme stuff for the first time so I was somewhat lost. Thank you!